# Why i can't give "1" as keyname in local Storage?

Tags: javascript

I want to give key name as "1" but its not working.

I want to pass a string like this in local storage with key "1" eg

```
1:["name":"kalidas"]
```

```
var array = [];
t = "kalidas";
t1 = "array";
if (localStorage.getItem("1") === null) {
  a = [
    {
      name: t,
    },
  ];
  localStorage.setItem("1", JSON.stringify(a));
  array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("1"));
} else {
  array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("1"));
  a = {
    name: t,
  };
  array.push(a);
  localStorage.setItem("1", JSON.stringify(array));
}
```

The output I'm always getting is Storage

```
{1: "1", length: 1}
```

However, if I change key name it works perfectly.

Comment: 1:["name":"kalidas"] is not valid syntax, also tested localStorage having "1" as key and there is no issue, not sure what you are doing

Comment: he probably meant `["name", "kalidas"]`

Comment: how can i get my key value to be "1" and an array inside that

Comment: I think he means [{"name":"kalidas"}] from the code

Comment: At no point does that code either try to set `1:["name":"kalidas"]` or produce `{1: "1", length: 1}`. When running this code, you put an array in local storage at key `1`.

Comment: @Eric, you're right, makes more sense

Comment: Storage {array: "[{"name":"kalidas"},{"name":"kalidas"}]", length: 1} if the key value is "array" i'm getting this output on running reloading twice

Comment: I want my key value to be "1".

Comment: @KalidasRajeev the key *where*? The object with the `name` property? The index of the array? The key where this is stored in `localStorage`?

Comment: You are getting that response because you are trying to log the localStorage object to the console `console.log(localStorage)`, if you try to do `localStorage.getItem("1")` instead, you should see the response `[{"name":"kalidas"}]`.. That would be the only explanation

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.setItem('1', 'Some String here')` works as expected.

Yes, the response of your code would be

```
[{…}]
   0: {name: "kalidas"}
   length: 1
```

If you look at your storage like `console.log(localStorage)` you will get

```
Storage {1: "1", length: 1}
   1: "1"
   length: 1
```

that's true

However, if you try to fetch stored data by key i.e. `localStorage.getItem('1')` you will get your valid response

```
"[{"name":"kalidas"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple wrapper that always roundtrips things to JSON:

```
function saveValue(key, value) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

function loadValue(key, defaultValue=null) {
  const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
  if(value === null) return defaultValue;
  return JSON.parse(value);
}

const a = {name: 'kalidas'};
saveLocalStorage('1', a);
const b = loadLocalStorage('1');
```

Comment: Why does this help? What's the problem with the original?

Comment: This is an example on how to encapsulate the saving/loading/hydration/dehydration most of all.